# Get json data from tcp connection php

Tags: php, python, json, tcp

I'm trying to connect to a python api and extracj json data.
It only accepts tcp connections but my script stop never closes the connections. It keeps reading.

```
$fp = fsockopen("dns", 5500, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8;');
    $out .= "Host: Host: dns\r\n";
    $out .="type=AF_CFG\r\nslaveName=+393471100223\r\nslaveID=1\r\nslaveLabel=APP001\r\nGroup=BETONROSSI\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
}
fclose($fp);
}
```

I think I'm not telling it to look for json data, how can I do it?

Comment: you can't use `urllib2.urlopen(the url)`??

Comment: @Raskayu I need to write on a GET/ HTTP1 and get the json data

Comment: Then just use [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) and [json lib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html)

Comment: @Raskayu but server only accepts TCP connections, doesn't matter?

Comment: HTTP works over TCP, and since you said GET/HTTP it's ok :)